# How to Remove All Database Connection Dependencies in an SSIS package

Tags: ssis, ssis-connection-manager

I have an SSIS package that contains a connection manager used for logging. The logging service has been deprecated and I have been tasked with removing references to it from the package. Before I delete the connection manager, I need to remove all references to it, but I haven't been able to figure out how to do that. Can anyone give me any advice? The target server of the package is SQL SERVER 2012, and I am editing the package with Visual Studio 2017.

Answer (score 2):

You would likely spend more time in analysis than just killing the connection manager and following the error list as your clean up punchlist.

1. Have package in source control
2. Delete connection manager
3. Close and reopen package and find and address all instances that show as broken.
4. Run package as there may be places (Script Task/Components come to mind) that might not know they're broken
5. Commit to source control.

Lather, rinse, repeat for all packages.

If you need to provide a list beforehand, you could reverse engineer the package to [Biml](http://www.varigence.com/BimlExpress) and then you'd have a much smaller domain of XML to sift through looking for references to your connection manager.